# UTC to Local Conversion in Where Statement

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a large table that has a datetime column stored in UTC. I've seen many, many posts asking how to convert from UTC to local, however they are all indicative of it being done in the select statement, instead of the where.

I have successfully used this in a select statement:

```
CASE WHEN (Number = 0 or Number is NULL) THEN GETDATE()
     WHEN Number = 1 THEN  DATEADD(mi,30,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),UTC_COLUMN))
     WHEN Number = 2 THEN  DATEADD(mi,240,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),UTC_COLUMN))
     WHEN Number = 3 THEN  DATEADD(mi,1170,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),UTC_COLUMN))
     WHEN Number = 4 THEN  DATEADD(mi,60,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),UTC_COLUMN))
     WHEN Number = 5 THEN  DATEADD(mi,540,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),UTC_COLUMN))
     WHEN Number = 6 THEN  DATEADD(mi,60,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),UTC_COLUMN))

     END AS RECORDS_IN_FILTER
```

However when trying to use it in the where I get the message "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'." Obviously, this is because the above is incompatible.

I'm trying to achieve the following in SSMS:

```
where (Number = 0 or Number is NULL)
(Number = 1 and ((UTC_COLUMN to GETDATE for Local)-30 minutes))
OR 
(Number = 2 and ((UTC_COLUMN to GETDATE for Local)-240 minutes))
OR 
(Number = 3 and ((UTC_COLUMN to GETDATE for Local)-1170 minutes))
OR 
(Number = 4 and ((UTC_COLUMN to GETDATE for Local)-60 minutes))
OR 
(Number = 3 and ((UTC_COLUMN to GETDATE for Local)-540 minutes))
OR 
(Number = 3 and ((UTC_COLUMN to GETDATE for Local)-60 minutes))
```

I need it to be in minutes because the query will be run every minute so will continuously pull records that fit that filter.

Thanks so much for any help!

Cheers,
Korey

Comment: this isnt a boolean expression though - ((UTC_COLUMN to Local)-30 minutes)...  ((UTC_COLUMN to Local)-30 minutes)>SYSDATE for example?

Comment: sorry @Ctznkane525, you're right. I've edited original post to show it more clearly

Comment: still not boolean expressions...what are you trying to compare the date to?...you need a comparison...greater than, less than or equal to something being the most common...between is another example

Comment: @Ctznkane525 sorry if I'm not being clear. want to pull a record that is 30 minutes in the past (9am local) from now (9:30am local) even though UTC column says 2018-07-11 23:00:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is then the change you need, sticking with # 1?

```
Number = 1 and UTC_COLUMN BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE()
```

- If The Column Is Greater Than 30 Minutes Prior to UTC Date Than Less Than UTC Date.
- This returns a boolean expression.

I think the other 6 are self explanatory.

Comment: 1Thank you @Ctznkane525! While not specifically the solution I used, it did allow me to do the following: 

(Number = '1' and UTC_COLUMN < DATEADD(minute, -30, GETUTCDATE()))